# Window's CMD simple program to rename files doesn't work with spaces

Tags: command-line, command, command-prompt, cmd

Hello everyone and thanks for your help!

I currently have this program that renames a single file to lowercase:

This file is Lowercase.bat

```
set LC1=%~nx1
set LC1=%LC1:"=%
set LC1=%LC1:A=a%
set LC1=%LC1:B=b%
set LC1=%LC1:C=c%
set LC1=%LC1:D=d%
set LC1=%LC1:E=e%
set LC1=%LC1:F=f%
set LC1=%LC1:G=g%
set LC1=%LC1:H=h%
set LC1=%LC1:I=i%
set LC1=%LC1:J=j%
set LC1=%LC1:K=k%
set LC1=%LC1:L=l%
set LC1=%LC1:M=m%
set LC1=%LC1:N=n%
set LC1=%LC1:O=o%
set LC1=%LC1:P=p%
set LC1=%LC1:Q=q%
set LC1=%LC1:R=r%
set LC1=%LC1:S=s%
set LC1=%LC1:T=t%
set LC1=%LC1:U=u%
set LC1=%LC1:V=v%
set LC1=%LC1:W=w%
set LC1=%LC1:X=x%
set LC1=%LC1:Y=y%
set LC1=%LC1:Z=z%
ren "%1" "%LC1%"
```

And I have this file that renames (supposively) every file and folder in every subfolder. It does it by calling the above batch multiple times

This is called LowerCaseRecursive.bat

```
pushd %1
dir *.* /b /a-d /s > lwrcase.log
for /f %%i in ('type lwrcase.log') do call LowerCase "%%i"
del /q lwrcase.log
popd
```

You call the program by using the command line and say LowerCaseRecursive.bat "C:\Test\". Everything works fine but it does NOT rename files that include a 
So everything works great, but it can't seem to rename files with a space on them, even though it has the full name in lwrcase.log. The for just parses until the first space.

I've little knowledge of windows batch programming, any ideas?

Thanks a lot everyone! If you have any questions about this just ask me.

EDIT: The problem is most likely on the individuals calls to lowercase.bat. Debugging I can see that the call to lowercase.bat already has the entire filename after the space cropped. Meaning that if the file is C:\Hello\My File.txt  it will call:

```
call Lowercase "C:\Hello\My"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read carefully the FOR help, accessed by typing `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from a command prompt. You will see that FOR /F parses each line into tokens, and the default token delimiters are space and tab.

You simply need to disable the token parsing by setting DELIMS to nothing. Technically, you should also set EOL to some character that can never start a path. The default EOL character is `;`. Any line that begins with `;` will be ignored, and `;` is valid in folder and file names (though very unusual). A path cannot begin with `:`, so that is a good choice.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%i in ('type lwrcase.log') do call LowerCase "%%i"
```

**EDIT**

Here are some unsolicited improvements to your code :-)

Your Lowercase.bat can be made much smaller. This works because the search part of search and replace is case insensitive.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "LC1=%~nx1"
for %%C in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  set "LC1=!LC1:%%C=%%C!"
)
ren %1 "!LC1!"
exit /b
```

And your LowerCaseRecursive.bat can also be greatly simplified into a single line.

```
for /r %1 %%F in (*) do call LowerCase "%%F"
```

Comment: Omg you are like 2 minutes late, I was reading the for help and I just solved it using something similar like that (adding tokens for each space, extra didn't matter) and I was about to answer my own question. Thanks!

Comment: Great info man, I didn't read the part that the default delims were space and tabs

Comment: Thats great. Thanks a lot! So it seems that there are people that use command prompt a lot =)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
set LC1=%LC1:' '=''%
```

little trick should work for you, Just follow the conversion pattern, and add `space ' '` line for you

Comment: Replacing the second line of lowercase using that gave the same result =(. I think that the problem is due to the way the second batch's for parses the stuff. Debugging I can see that **the call to LowerCase "%%i" already has the entire string after the space cropped**, meaning that the problem is most likely on LowerCaseRecursive.bat. I'll edit my question for further details. Upvoted for helping! =)

Comment: The OP does not want to remove the spaces, and this would not solve the problem anyway.